# TypeError: unhashable type: 'ListWidgetItem'

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2

I have some PySide2 code that works well from a python2.7 environment... but when run in python3.7, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<Python Editor Contents>", line 17, in <module>
    widget.resized.connect(item.resize_to_widget_size)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'ListWidgetItem'
```

Here's a simplified example of the code:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class ListWidgetItem(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListWidgetItem, self).__init__()

    def resize_to_widget_size(self, width, height):
        self.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(width, height))

class WidgetExample(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    resized = QtCore.Signal(int, int)
    def __init__(self):
        super(WidgetExample, self).__init__()

item = ListWidgetItem()
widget = WidgetExample()
widget.resized.connect(item.resize_to_widget_size)
```

I understand that the QListWidgetItem is not hashable... but I don't quite understand why there's a hash attempt in python3.

Could someone please explain this to me and possibly offer a solution.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in PySide2. The same code works in PySide6 and PyQt5.

Comment: try with: `widget.resized.connect(lambda item=item: item.resize_to_widget_size)`

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc ! No error is raised when using `lamdba`

Comment: This bug has now been fixed in PySide2. I don't know which specific version it was fixed in, but I can no longer reproduce it with the following setup: python-3.10.9, qt 5.15.8, shiboken-5.15.8, pyside-5.15.8.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution did not work on my side. I'm actually surprised that I cannot find a lot of discussion on this matter in the web since this seems to me a pretty annoying bug.

Using lambda did not help on my side. I got strange errors like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...mymodule.py", line 53, in <lambda>
    widget.resized.connect(lambda item=item: item.resize_to_widget_size)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'resize_to_widget_size'
```

No clue why it talks about 'int' objects. When printing the item, I have my custom QListWidgetItem as expected.

To fix this on my side, instead of connecting the signal to a function on the item, I use an intermediate function like this:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import functools

class ListWidgetItem(QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListWidgetItem, self).__init__()

    def resize_to_widget_size(self, width, height):
        self.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(width, height))

class WidgetExample(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    resized = QtCore.Signal(int, int)
    def __init__(self):
        super(WidgetExample, self).__init__()

    def my_slot(self, item, width, height):
        item.resize_to_widget_size(width, height)

item = ListWidgetItem()
widget = WidgetExample()
widget.resized.connect(functools.partial(widget.my_slot, item))
```

Comment: That error is because the signal has arguments, while you're assuming that the first value refers to the item. Change to `lambda width, height, item=item: item.resize_to_widget_size(width, height)` (the `item=item` can be skipped if there's no issue with scopes, like getting `item` in a loop).